# Fetching latest version of app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to provide an in-app badge to the users to let them know about the latest version of app available on the store. How do I connect to Play Store and fetch this information? Is there any SDK or API?

Comment: "Is there any SDK or API?" -- none that are documented, supported, or licensed.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html - this link has info on how  to redirect users of your app to the store. As for ascertaining the availability of an update, it would be easy to just serve a document off your own website that has the latest version number.

Comment: but I want to know the latest version before redirecting user to this page. This is HTML page, I want something like iTunes provides - https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---search-api.html